# Grub not showing during start

Tags: grub2

I have an HP laptop with Windows 10 installed.
I tried to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 on it. During installation, I got grub-install  failed on /dev/sda fatal error. To fix it I, used boot repair: it showed success.
But after reboot, it still loads directly to Windows 10.

It is not showing grub screen at start.

I don't know how to fix this.

PasteLink http://paste.ubuntu.com/26050842/

Comment: is /sda6 flagged as an ESP partition? You should have used /sda3 for the ESP partition when you installed Ubuntu. Your system may not recognize 2 ESP partitions on a single drive. And third, did you change boot order in the system settings? (check this last one first).

Comment: Ya I tried changing boot order using command prompt bcdedit command as said in the result of boot-repair

Comment: I said in `System Settings`, not Windows. EFI firmware that allows OS selection will often ignore the order set by bcdedit.

Comment: Can u tell me how to do that, since I'm new to linux, I don't know how to do that

Comment: it has nothing to do with linux .... press a function key while booting, the specific key depends on the computer; though F2, F10, and F12 are common. Keep trying until you get the system settings, not the onetime boot selection screen.

Comment: Under UEFI boot order, at first OS boot manager is there

Comment: and the OS it is pointed to? does Ubuntu show as a selection? Note: since the grub install failed (as you noted earlier)  even if you get grub to boot, it will drop to rescue mode since it didn't finish installing. There are many posts here about how to fix that.

Comment: No, Ubuntu doesn't show in that, do I need to reinstall Ubuntu or what, can u give me links of posts which solve this

Comment: first, copy the files from /sda6 to /sda3. You will have to create the ubuntu folder. then try to set boot OS. If bootrepair created grubs config file, you may be ok.

Comment: When I select boot options it shows Ubuntu when I click that it shows grub that displays option to select windows 10 or Ubuntu

Comment: select ubuntu/grub

Comment: I selected Ubuntu and it booted successfully, when I select windows 10 it also boots

Comment: ok, to be sure .... you change the boot order setting and not just used the boot select menu, so that the change is recoreded in the firmware.

Comment: But in UEFI boot order , it not shows Ubuntu.  In boot options only it shows Ubuntu when clicking that it shows grub to choose

Comment: did you copy the files from /sda6 to /sda3?

Answer (score 0):

Hold down and keep pressing the shift key during the boot process and your machine should boot into the Grub menu.

Comment: It boots to windows only not boot into Grub